# Add Check constraint in SQL

Tags: sql, constraints

I'm facing a problem. (I've just studying SQL for 2 weeks)
I'm doing an assignment about airport flight management.

In my assignment, my teacher asked me to add a constraint, which is: "At the same StartDate, There are no 2 flights at the same time at the same Departing Airport". My idea is that if Count(StartDate) > 1, then I add constraint UNIQUE in Departing Airport and StartTime, but it seems impossible. Anyone here can give me some idea?

[image: Schema of my DB]
(The line I mark bold is Primary Key and the arrow is Foreign Key)

Comment: Why do you think adding a unique constraint on the departing airport and start time is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add unique constraint on `departing_airpot`, `stardate` and `starttime`.

```
Alter table <table_name> add Unique(departing_airport, startdate, starttime)
```

Comment: hmmm, I think it has a problem, because the startdate can be duplicate, but at the same startdate, there's no duplicate flight at the same departing airport, so that I think if we add Unique to all of these, there will cause mistake.

Comment: It will not allow to add the same flight at same startdate and starttime.